# Unir data.frames em R

Tags: r

Olá.

Tenho dois data.frames. Segue:

```
head(dadosFiltradosBand)
 rdf.schema.label                                        genre_label
4 The Valentines (rock band)                             {Pop music|Rock music}
5    The Valentino Orchestra                                               NULL
6             The Valentinos {Rhythm and blues|Soul music|Doo-wop|Gospel music}
7        The Valerie Project                                   Psychedelic folk
8          The Valley (band)                   {Alternative rock|Post-hardcore}
9                   The Vals {Folk music|Psychedelic rock|Pop music|Rock music}

head(dadosFiltradosMusicalArtist)
  rdf.schema.label                                             genre_label
4         MC Primo                                            Funk carioca
5     MC Raaka Pee              {Death metal|Gothic rock|Industrial metal}
6          MC Rage                 Hardcore (electronic dance music genre)
7           MC Ren {Gangsta rap|G-funk|Hardcore hip hop|Political hip hop}
8          MC Rene                                                    NULL
9          MC Ride                    {Hip hop music|Experimental hip hop}
```

Preciso atribuir todos os dados de cada um dos dois data.frames a um novo data.frame, onde `rdf.schema.label` e `genre_label` de `dadosFiltradosBand` e `rdf.schema.label` e `genre_label` de `dadosFiltradosMusicalArtist` fiquem um abaixo do outro.

Basicamente, quero manter as mesmas duas colunas no novo data frame, quero apenas acrescentar os dados de um data.frame abaixo do outro.

Encontrei muita coisa sobre, mas de forma a unir e criar duas novas colunas.

Comment: `novoDF = rbind(dadosFiltradosBand, dadosFiltradosMusicalArtist)`?

Comment: Se a sugestão do @WillianVieira não resultar por as colunas serem de classe `"factor"`, mude-as primeiro com `as.character()`.

Comment: A sugestão de @WillianVieira funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para unir os 2 data.frames em linhas você pode usar a função `rbind.data.frame` ou somente `rbind`. Entretanto, no seu caso vai dar erro falando que os data.frames tem nomes de colunas diferentes. Você vai precisar renomear as colunas de modo que tenham o mesmo nome. O código abaixo deve resolver seu problema:

```
names(dadosFiltradosMusicalArtist) <- names(dadosFiltradosBand)
novosDados <- rbind.data.frame(dadosFiltradosMusicalArtist, dadosFiltradosBand)
```